# Цього року чи в цей рік?

Tags: прийменники, помилки

В українській мові часто зустрічається така форма позначення року:

> **В 2017 році** на українську економіку чекає неабиякий ріст

Натомість [знавці](http://nepravylno-pravylno.wikidot.com/pryimennyky) мови [радять](https://ukr-mova.in.ua/library/antusurzhuk/czogo-roku-j-torik) [вживати](https://books.google.es/books?id=Yw5ZFwkZhEsC&pg=PA19&lpg=PA19&dq=%D0%B2%20%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%86%D1%96%20%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%20%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83&source=bl&ots=lElRr-nuMW&sig=l1ktrkIcB0fs9IN2DtKdUhVDm5k&hl=uk&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiule7q88vSAhVlAsAKHV4kCkc4ChDoAQgZMAA#v=onepage&q=%D0%B2%20%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%86%D1%96%20%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%20%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83&f=false) наступну [конструкцію](http://onlinecorrector.com.ua/%D1%86%D1%8C%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83-%D1%86%D1%8C%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%96%D1%87/):

> **2017 року** на українську економіку чекає неабиякий ріст

Чи є обидві форми правильними?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Антоненко-Давидович пише у "Як ми говоримо":

> Прийменником у (в) з іменником у знахідному відмінку
>   послугуємось, визначаючи час за днями тижня: "у вівторок", "у
>   п'ятницю", – або з іменником у місцевому відмінку, коли мовиться про
>   місяці року: "у січні", "у липні". Проте, коли визначається час за
>   роком, треба користуватись родовим відмінком іменника, а не
>   прийменником у (в) з іменником у місцевому відмінку: ближче буде до
>   нашої мовної традиції **цього року, а не в цьому році, 1970 року, а не в
>   1970 році**. Так само слід казати торік, а не в минулому році,
>   позаторік, а не в позаминулому році; аналогічні будуть і прикметники –
>   торішній, а не минулорічний, позаторішній, а не позаминулорічний.

За [посиланням](http://www.notabe.net/antonenko-davydovych-b-d-yak-my-hovorymo.html) є стисла табличка, що базується на інформації з цієї книги, а саме із статей [Родовий відмінок часу](http://slovopedia.org.ua/34/53408/33115.html), [Орудний відмінок часу](http://slovopedia.org.ua/34/53406/33119.html) та [Прийменники](http://slovopedia.org.ua/34/53408/33115.html):

```
Родовий відмінок     Іменники, що означають    (+) того дня, цього літа,
                     конкретний час                темної ночі
                                               (–) у той день, у це літо,
                                                   у темну ніч


Орудний відмінок     Іменники, що означають    (+) останнім часом, цими днями,
                     невизначений час              іншим часом
                                               (–) в останній час, на цих днях,
                                                   у інший час


Знахідний відмінок   Форма множини, а також    (+) у ті дні, у вівторок, 
+ прийменник         іменник без означення     (–) тих днів, по вівторках
```

Answer (score 5):

«В (у) такому-то році» — це одна з тих речей, які люди де-факто завжди використовували:

- Ґрунтів спільно уживаних було [в 1895 роцї] в 67 повітах, а в 4.986 громадах 617028 м. 670 с., а то: пасовиск 417722 м., лісів 124694 м., <…>. //«Хлопська політика» ([1902](//books.google.com/books?id=nR8tAQAAMAAJ&q=%22%D0%B2+1895+%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%86%D1%96%22)).
- Надїя Констянтинівна Кибальчич родила ся в 1878. роцї в старій українській родинї з лїтературними традиціями. //«Вістник Союза визволення України» ([1914](//books.google.com/books?id=w-rTAAAAMAAJ&q=%22%D0%B2%22+%22%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%86%D1%96%22)).
- У цьому році прислали декілька праць на конкурс, між ними також товариші з провінції, що є позитивним явищем. //Журнал «Лікарський вісник» ([1936](//books.google.com/books?id=rvsvAAAAIAAJ&q=%22%D1%83+%D1%86%D1%8C%D0%BE%D0%BC%D1%83+%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%86%D1%96%22)).

Те, що зазначення часових періодів є однією з функцій прийменника «в» («у») доводить, наприклад, те, що нам важко сказати «двадцятого століття науково-технічний прогрес значно прискорився» (лише «у двадцятому столітті») або «1930-х років відбулося масове нищення української інтелігенції» (лише «у 1930-х роках»). Також непрямо це доводиться тим, що нам незручно в деяких випадках застосовувати родовий відмінок навіть до років, як от у книжці книжки В'ячеслава Будзиновського «Хлопська посілість в Галичині і новочасні суспільно-реформаторські змагання» ([1895](//books.google.com/books?&id=4s5jAAAAcAAJ&q=%22%D0%B2+%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%86%D1%96%22)):
[image: -сти виносило в році: 1868 — 465.513 зр. / 1878 — 15.155.479 ,, / 1888 — 43.523.542 ,,]

Проте я підтримую мовознавців (що виступають за використання «такого-то року») ось у чому… Конструкція «такого-то року» (на відміну від «у такому-то році») відсутня в російській мові. Оскільки російська мова (очевидно) спричиняє на українську мову певний вплив, не хотілося би, щоби варіант «такого-то року» просто поступово зник із ужитку через поступове витіснення таким варіантом, що є і в російській.

Тож: не забуваймо про «такого-то року»; але «в (у) такому-то році» теж завжди існувало.